# can't access property of json object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I can't seem to reach my object variables, I'm probably just doing a dummy mistake somewhere. A console.log of my array of objects (pResult) look like this, first object expanded but they all look alike:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

0: Object
depTime: "2014-12-04 18:35"
destination: "Norsesund station"
nr: "562"
operator: "Västtrafik"
typText: "Buss"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
length: 9
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I try to do this...

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= pResult.length; i++) {
    var html =  html + '<tr>';
    var html =  html + '<td>';
    var html =  html + pResult[i].depTime;
    var html =  html + '</td>';
    var html =  html + '</tr>';
}
```

...but get hit with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'depTime' of undefined
```

Comment: According to your output, `pResult.depTime` is defined, but `pResult[i].depTime` is not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just an aside: this has nothing to do with JSON; you're dealing with JavaScript objects, not textual notation that describes objects. (If your question dealt with parsing JSON text into objects, then the `[json]` tag would be appropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change :

```
i <= pResult.length;
```

To:

```
i < pResult.length;
```

Array is 0 based indexed, so if it has length 3, you only have indexes 0,1,2

Comment: This is what I saw pResult does not exist for pResult[9] ... 9 being the length.

Comment: thank you, works. will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop, you can simply use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var html = pResult.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + '<tr><td>' + currentValue.depTime + '</td></tr>';
}, '');
```

Note that this only works on IE 9+ (but it works in all other modern browsers), so if you need to support older versions of IE, you can polyfill the method.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pResult.length; i++) {
        var html =   '<tr>';
            html +=  html + '<td>';
                html +=  html + pResult[i].depTime;
            html +=  html + '</td>';
        html +=  html + '</tr>';
}
```

The problem is you are loopin until arrays length but array start at 0 index so 
 if you have array
`var pResult= [object,object,object];` 
 `pResult.length =3` 
  `pResult[3]` doesnt exist so it is undefined.
**NOTE** dont recreate the variable when you just want to add text just add it to the existing one For example html+=" the added text"